# Create schedule to turn off iOS device every night..?

Tags: ios, ipad, battery, settings, ipados

Is there a way to automatically turn off an iOS device every night (say from *0:00* to *6:00*) to save battery WiFi bandwidth?

There's an iPad mini in our living room basically running as Spotify/Podcast player which we don't normally use in the evening and certainly not at night, 
and the battery tends to be drained if we forget to turn it off.

Android has a setting for scheduled shutdown but searching through the iOS settings (11.3) didn't reveal a thing.

Comment: Can you keep it plugged into a power source? That'll eliminate the need to shut it down. I have an old iPad I use to keep connected via Bluetooth to various [SensePeanut devices](https://sen.se/store/c/peanuts/) in my house. It needs to be plugged into a power source 24/7.

Comment: Sure - but the battery wear.. though apparently no longer as bad an issue according to Alexander's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no feature for automatic turning off with no jailbreak.
However, you can:

1. Schedule "[Do not disturb mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204321)" and it will not turn you screen on to show useless notifications
2. Manually turn on "[Low power mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234)" to stop all background processes and save your battery.
3. Plug it into a power source with no worries, since iOS 11.3 iPad has a new "[iPad Charge Management Feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208710)"

Comment: Thanks - pity. I suppose I'll have to live with a power supply permanently attached in this this case for the time being..

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that no such thing exists. The best you can is to schedule it to go into Do Not Disturb mode overnight, which will save a little battery, but not very much.

Comment: That would be a pity! Thanks for the hint, though…